# Why is tableView overlapping the status at the top?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I've created a Tab view controller and made one of the tabs a TableViewController with a Table View. What I don't understand is why the table view overlaps the status at the top in the simulator? here's a screen shot

[image]

Shouldn't the table view automatically adjust downwards to avoid that top bit? What can I do to reformat that? should I just turn the top status off? of move the table view down somehow?

Answer (score 3):

You can either add a navigation bar to the screen, or if you really do not need that, you can move the top of the `tableview` down by 20 points to adjust for the status bar.  In iOS7+ the status bar is put over the screen.  It is part of the OS design, where prior versions would move everything down.

As stated in a comment below, the status bar might not always be 20.0f.  You could check programmatically on `viewWillAppear` and adjust the tableview frame accordingly.  To get the status bar height programmatically you can do the following:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height
```

As some answers have posted, you could edit the content inset of the tableview but I do not recommend this because when you scroll the content, it will still go underneath the status bar.

Comment: I assume you meant 20 points, not 20 pixels. But the status bar is not always 20 points high, so your solution will not always work.

Answer (score 0):

From [How do I prevent the status bar from covering my views in iOS 7?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html):

> You need to use Auto Layout and apply a vertical spacing anchored to the "Top Layout Guide" of your view controller.

If you require more specific steps, click the link and follow the steps under "Add the Vertical Space Constraint to the top-most view".

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, check that your `UIViewControllers` or `UITableViewController` have `Adjust Scroll View Insets` set to checked.

If that does not work for tab views for some reasons, you can programmatically change the inset of the `UITableView`.

```
_tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
_tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = _tableView.contentInset;
```

Comment: That will adjust the content inset, but won't stop the status bar from overlapping with the content.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically include the header spacing at the top of your view, embed your Table View Controller inside of a Navigation Controller. To do this:

1. Open your storyboard in Xcode.
2. Click on your Table View Controller item within your storyboard.
3. Within the Xcode menu, select the `Editor` --> `Embed In` -> `Navigation Controller` menu item.

You will notice that a Navigation Controller was inserted in front of your Table View Controller and your contents will not overlap the status bar.